# iOS - How to make rotation on the center of image when orientation changed

Tags: ios, orientation, screen-rotation

In Apple Photos App, when it is rotated from portrait to landscape. The image will rotate on its center point. However, the photo app created myself just not rotate on the center point.

The structure is like this..
 [image]

When it rotates to landscape.. it will look like following
[image]

And Then I'll tile the pages(ImageScrollView) in

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

is there anyone know how to make it rotate on the center of screen?

Comment: it won't rotate the images automatically. U gotta do it by urself. Change the frame size of the scrollView, ContentSize of it and then set the frame of your imageViews accordingly

Comment: I suggest you to go through this article first : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ushan87 Thanks..

Found the answer..
set the image frame must be done in

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

and the view will rotate on it's center